# How do I replace a value in my dataframe with text?

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with dates from April 2020 to today, right now they are labelled 1 to 492 with 1 being the first date I have data on. I also have a list of dates in the format I want. How can I tell R that date 1 is april 12 2020, date 2 is april 13, 2020, and so on for each date? I'm ok either replacing the values in the column or creating a new column called real_date next to it.

Update:
Sorry I didn't describe this very well. I ended up making a look-up table with the date number and real date, and I used the inner_join function to add the real date to my dataframe.

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example?  When you say labelled is it a separate column?  Do you want `seq(as.Date('2020-04-12'), length.out = 492, by = '1 day')`

Comment: Yes, sorry! The first column is called "date" and it ranges from 1 to 492.  I hadn't thought to do it like that., I was planning on making a new dataframe with just the list of dates in one column and numbers 1 through 492 next to it, then using that as like a lookup table. But I'll try using mutate and then the code you provided (Sorry if this isn't clear, I'm very new to R and still learning how to describe it.)

Comment: In that case it is more easier i.e. `data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2020-04-12'), length.out = 492, by = '1 day'), code = 1:492)`

Comment: Would that work if each date has a different number of rows? If each row was a different date I could do that but some dates have 59 rows and some have 58

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#Creating a sample data.frame
df <-
  tibble(
    dates = seq.Date(dmy("01/04/20"),today(),by = "1 day")
  )

df %>% 
  #Format date, where: %B = month as string, %d numeric day and %y numeric year 
  mutate(
    new_date = format(dates,"%B %d %Y")
  )
```

[image]

**Abril is April in portuguese.*

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `seq`uence of dates

```
data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2020-04-12'), length.out = 492,
 by = '1 day'), code = 1:492)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, you have a dataframe which has numbers from 1 to 492, now you want to change them to dates where number 1 is 12th April 2020, number 2 is 13th April 2020 and so on.

You can use `as.Date` to convert these numbers to date and pass the origin as 11th April.

```
df <- data.frame(date = 1:492)
df$real_date <- as.Date(df$date, origin = '2020-04-11')
head(df)

#  date  real_date
#1    1 2020-04-12
#2    2 2020-04-13
#3    3 2020-04-14
#4    4 2020-04-15
#5    5 2020-04-16
#6    6 2020-04-17
```